# What does it mean that a prime number "$l$" is invertible in a scheme X?

Tags: algebraic-geometry, sheaf-theory, schemes

What does it mean that a prime number "$l$" is invertible in a scheme X?

Thanks you all.

Comment: It means that $X$, regarded as a scheme over $\text{Spec } \mathbb{Z}$, descends to a scheme over $\text{Spec } \mathbb{Z}[\ell^{-1}]$. More concretely, it means that $X$ is covered by affine opens of the form $\text{Spec } R_i$ where $\ell$ is invertible in each $R_i$.